# I want to know which word is duplicated on a line and how many times it appears in a file

Tags: awk, sed, cut, gawk

example:  I have file `a.txt` that contains the following:

```
aunt bear bear true
```

I also have a file `b.txt` that contains the following:

```
tru tru high
```

the end result I want is :

```
for a.txt : bear x 2
for b.txt : tru x 2
```

So far, I can only think of this:

```
cut -d ' ' -f1 file.txt | sort | uniq -c | head -1
```

I am quite out of ideas

The sorting need to be done on the files; clarification: when introducing the files c.txt  b.txt  y.txt the content of b should be first and the content of y last

Comment: Is this an idea? `grep -Eo '[^[:blank:]]+' a.txt b.txt | awk '{count=++seen[$1]; if (count >= 2) print $FILENAME,count}'`   This means that each row is seperated by a `space`

Comment: Does the work need to appear multiple times in a row? Or you're counting how many times the word occurs in the file as a whole? Are you looking for the most popular word only? What if there's a tie?

Comment: What do you actually need to know? Your examples imply you want to see the counts for words that appear more than once in a file. Your title says something completely different and you left a comment suggesting you are only interested in repetitions on the same line. Please [edit] your question and clarify what you need so we don't waste your time (or ours) giving you solutions that don't work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple, fast approach that should work for arbitrary file names and file contents:

```
$ for file in a.txt b.txt ; do 
    printf 'for %s : %s\n' "$file" "$(tr ' ' '\n' < "$file" | sort | uniq -dc)"; 
  done
for a.txt :       2 bear
for b.txt :       2 tru
```

Or, if you really need *exactly* the format you show:

```
$ for file in a.txt b.txt ; do 
    printf 'for %s : %s x %s\n' "$file" \
        $(tr ' ' '\n' < "$file" | sort | uniq -dc | awk '{print $2,$1}');
  done
for a.txt : bear x 2
for b.txt : tru x 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ for i in $(cat a.txt); do echo $i; done | sort | uniq -c | sort -g | tail -1
      2 bear
```

script:

```
$ cat topword.sh
#!/bin/bash

FILENAMES=$@

for file in $@; do
    printf "$file:"
    cat $file | tr ' ' '\n' | sort | uniq -c | sort -g | tail -1
done
```

Output:

```
$ bash topword.sh a.txt b.txt
a.txt:      2 bear
b.txt:      2 tru
```

Now here is a task for you: make a nice looking easily read script out of this draft I gave you ;)

Comment: What if one of the words is `*`?  What if one input file has spaces in its name?

Comment: What if one of the words is `*`? - then we have to avoid using `echo`. Maybe use `cat` to print and `tr` to replace spaces with newlines? || What if one input file has spaces in its name? - We have `\\` for such cases. As I said, its a draft I made in like a minute. It has a lot of room for improvement, especially depending on the specific "bigger" task the OP wants to acomplish.

Comment: I updated the script to work with `*` words.

Comment: @filbranden I guess it'll still work, just will take longer.

Comment: Spaces in names -> quote your variables: `cat "$file"`

Comment: it's a cool idea but the problem is that if the same word appeared on 2 lines in the same file the count for that respective word would still go up, I wanted to raed the file line by line and then print the word that came up the most on one respective line

Comment: @Andrei Please add clarifications such as these to the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

A simple awk command will do the magic here

First step  since we need to calculate how many times a particular word occurs in a file

step1: Creating new inputfile based on the input file

```
cat input file |sed -r "s/\s+/\n/g" >inputfile_final.txt
```

Step2: Now Simple awk command with associate  array will do magic now

```
awk '{a[$1]++}END{for(x in a){print FILENAME, x,a[x]}}' inputfile_final.txt | sort -k3 -nr| sed -n '1p'| awk '{print "for" " " $1 " " ":" $2 " " "x" " "  $NF}'
```

output

```
for inputfile_final.txt :bear x 2


Note: I have done for 1 file same method we can follow for remaining files too
```